# I cant seem to get imagemagick working on amazon web services

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Basically I've been struggling for a while now on getting `imagemagick` and or `graphicsmagick` to run properly with my node app. So far I followed the installation source from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix

Details on my server include

- `nodejs`
- `mongodb`
- `mongoose`
- `imagemagick`
- `graphicsmagick`
- `express`

and it seems the installation went well. However when I run the code through node with [gm](https://npmjs.org/package/gm), I don't get any errors but the files don't get written. I'll post an example code of the image post function.

```
var gm = require('./gm');
var newRoute = '/some/user/url/';
var files = req.files;
gm(files.file.path).resize(1126).compress('JPEG').quality(quality)
.write(newRoute,function(err){

   //do some stuff to save changes on db

});
```

Now this is currently working perfectly on my local device. However on the server it wont budge. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on?.

The app creates folders and the folders modes are supposed to be `0777`, though when I log in with `ssh` it seems like they might be `0755', although Im not sure it's all that to do with permissions since I've got mp3 uploads working fine. It's when`imagemagick`and`graphicsmagick` come in to play that this happens. Any Ideas?

Comment: "by the colors?" You're *guessing* about permissions?  rwxrwxrwx is 0777 while rwxr-xr-x is 0755 and that is an extremely significant difference. No place for guesswork.

Comment: My guess is that either `resize` or `compress` don't produce any output, and that's why a file does not get written. This could happen due to partial installation (missing installed modules? Missing modules during build?). I propose you break the long processing chain into parts, and print the result after each part, to see where it breaks. Start with `files.file.path`.